# Receive id and model dynamically

Tags: laravel

Maybe a stupid question.
Is it possible to use a wildcard in the builder so that it can receive different models?

My idea is that the same notification can receive notifications about the model Post, Comments, etc.

Currently my notification is created like this:

**NOTIFICATION**

class UserNotification extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

```
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Post $post, $action)
    {
        $this->post= $post;
        $this->action = $action;

    }
```

Is it possible to pass to the constructor an id and a model and build the query dynamically? something like that:

```
public function __construct(Model? $model, $action)
        {
            $this->model= Model::findOrFail($model);
            $this->action = $action;
        }
```

and $model can be any model

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? You could add an interface to all common entities

Comment: Thank you very much, I am quite new and did not know the concept of interfaces. I will study it